# Calling a Form2 button Click event from Form1 Button Click event

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

I use D7 how can I call button click event of Form2 from Form1 Button click event ..

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
//-- here should go calling button click event of Form2
Form2.show;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
Form2.Button1.Click;
```

Note however, that it is often indicative of poor design for code in one form to poke at the GUI objects of another form. It might be better for the other form to offer a public method that can be called to perform whatever action is required.

Answer (score 0):

If procedure is declared as public at Form2 you can call it.